# Python 3 Turtle Graphics: Mouse coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, turtle-graphics

I want my turtle to point towards the cursor, but I don't want to click while doing it. If I move the cursor, the direction of the turtle should move accordingly. turtle.onscreenclick() is not helping me do this.

```
import turtle
def point_to_cursor():
    # What goes here?
    rec.ontimer(point_to_cursor,50)    
if __name__=="__main__":
    rec = turtle.Screen()
    rec.screensize(960,540)
    rec.setworldcoordinates(0,0,960,540)

    reflector = turtle.Turtle()
    reflector.up()
    reflector.goto(480,270)
    reflector.color("#0000ff")
    reflector.turtlesize(2,2,None)

    point_to_cursor()
    rec.listen()
    rec.mainloop()
```